# C++ Singleton fail to link on Mac OS

Tags: c++, macos

I am trying to create a very classic singleton on C++, Mac OS using Xcode
I create the Class MySingleton as follow:

```
class MySingleton{
private:
    int val;
    static MySingleton *instance;
    MySingleton(){
        val = 0;
    }
public:
    int getVal(){
        return val;
    }
    void setVal(int iVal){
        val = iVal;
    }
    static MySingleton* getInstance(){
        if(instance == NULL)
            instance = new MySingleton();
        return instance;
    }

};
```

Linker is complaining about **static MySingleton* getInstance()**
Follow the Linker message:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "MySingleton::instance",
>   referenced from:
>         MySingleton::getInstance() in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could somebody help on this?  Perhaps I need to set something on Xcode, which by the way is version 4.2.1, and I am not able in doing this.
Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can see, you've declared `static MySingleton *instance` but haven't defined it anywhere.

Comment: So silly!!!! Thanks  ta.speot.is!!!

Answer (score 6):

You need to define static variable in your cpp file, like this:

```
MySingleton *MySingleton::instance = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The static member MySingleton needs to be defined in the cpp file. In the header you have have only declared it. See this for more information: [Why do static variables need to be declared twice in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967713/why-do-static-variables-need-to-be-declared-twice-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you've declared `static MySingleton *instance` but haven't defined it anywhere.